# Automatic adjustment of framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I need to do something like this:

[image]

This application's user interface has one area containing multiple colored rectangles and another containing a  SeekBar. When the user drags the SeekBar, the rectangles    gradually change their color.

I'm using framelayouts (I don't know if there is something better) but I hardcoded the size of each framelayout and, of course, that is a bad idea.
How can I adapt the framelayouts and mantain the relations?

[image]

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_block"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"></FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_block_b"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_below="@id/first_block"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"></FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_block"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="165dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"></FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/med_block"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="165dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/second_block"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"></FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/last_block"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="165dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/med_block"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"></FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_block"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_block_b"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_block"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/med_block"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/last_block"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The above uses nested weights, which are sometimes bad for performance, but given what you're trying to do, it's the best option short of calculating them in code.

Comment: Works fine! thank you. In terms of performance what is the best option?

Comment: What you have is probably easiest to manage.  You can also do calculations in code and draw to canvas by overriding onDraw() (not straightforward), or override onSizeChanged() of a custom container, and re-layout the view yourself doing basic math. I would stick with the above until you get a better sense of the framework.